# Need to add 'br' tag after the last <group> element under 'block' element

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to add 'br' tag after 'group' element under the block element. Basically after the 'group' element in we want break page, that's why we are trying to add break page in output. Below is our input xml structure.
I tried on below XSLT code but unable to get result, please help on this issue:
**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page>
    <stream>
        <block>
            <group>content here</group>
            <group>content here</group>
            <group>content here</group>
        </block>
    </stream>
    <stream>
        <block>
            <group>content here</group>
            <group>content here</group>
            <group>content here</group>
            <!-- please add here br tag -->
        </block>
    </stream>
</page>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="group">
        <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <br></br>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><page>
    <stream>
        <block>
            <p>content here</p>
            <p>content here</p>
            <p>content here</p>
        </block>
    </stream>
    <stream>
        <block>
            <p>content here</p>
            <p>content here</p>
            <p>content here</p>
            <!-- please add here br tag -->
        </block>
    </stream>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would match on `<xsl:template match="group[last()]">` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="group[last()]">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

and for the other `group`s it seems you want

```
<xsl:template match="group">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

It is not clear, however, why your verbal description asks to add a `br` after the last `group` of a block while your sample has two blocks and you only add the `br` in the last block of the last stream. So perhaps you want `<xsl:template match="stream[last()]/block/group[last()]">` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="stream[last()]/block/group[last()]">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
Yes, In sample there are two blocks but I need add <br> in the last <block> tag

Comment: @KitaAnsari, both `block`s are the last `block` children in their respective `stream` parent so I think my second suggestion using `match="stream[last()]/block/group[last()]"` should help to identify the element where you want to add a `br` element.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, your second suggestion is working fine,